# Select two columns of similar types in a Linq Query

Tags: sql, linq

I have one weird requirement. 
In a SQL table, I have two columns of same type, say type ObjA. The values in these two columns repeats.

```
e.g.  ObjA_Column1    ObjA_Column2
      obj1               obj2  
      obj2               obj3
      obj1               obj2
      obj3               obj4
      obj4               obj5
```

I want a query that merge two column elements distinctively i.e.

```
ObjA_TembColumn
     obj1
     obj2
     obj3
     obj4
     obj5
```

Please help.

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dc.Table.Select(x => x.Column1).Union(dc.Table.Select(x => x.Column2))
```

Comment: Thanks Leppie. 
well.. that's is an easy one. But I forgot to mention that I also want to add the selection criteria 
suppose

dc.Table.Where(row=>row.Id == uid).Select(x => x.Column1).Union(dc.Table.Where(row=>row.Id == uid).Select(x => x.Column2))